# sendJavascript not working in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have made a phonegap plugin application on android. I am trying to send String value from Java Code to JavaScript using the `sendJavaScript API` in Phonegap. But I am facing a problem. If the string contains a single quote, then `sendJavaScript` does not work. Without single quote, it works perfectly fine. Following is the code, in the java file of Plugin class.

```
String result = "Any text except single quote ";
String SendJS = "javascript:" + SuccessCallBack + "('" + JSONObject.quote(result) +    "')"; 
sendJavaScript(SendJS);
```

`SuccessCallBack` - Callback function in the JavaScript.

`result` - String to be passed to JavaScript Callback.

If the result string contains a single quote, then sendJavaScript does not work.

**Any Suggestions?**

Comment: I have the same issue did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the string before sending it by using http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html (Either the JS or HTML one). Unescape it using unescape(string) on the JS side, that should help you out.